# Grails 4 upgrade - Error message unable to find a single main class

Tags: grails, grails-4

I am currently upgrading from Grails 3.3.10 to Grails 4.0.0. When attempting to run my project I get the following error:

```
 Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
 15:31:02.101 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Unable to find a single main class from the following candidates [com.torque.Application, com.base.torque.ExtendedReportsController, com.base.torque.utils.NaturalOrderComparator]
```

Whether I try to run the project in my IDE or my terminal, I get the same error.

I uninstalled and reinstalled grails 4.0.0 and I still get the error. Tried `./gradlew clean`, rebuilding, `killall -9 java` and still get the error.

This was not an issue with previous Grails versions. No clue what is causing the issue with Grails 4 and no clue how to solve. Any insight towards a solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a `main` method in `com.base.torque.utils.NaturalOrderComparator` and `com.base.torque.ExtendedReportsController`?

Comment: It would be very strange to have a `main` method in a controller or a comparator, but the error message suggests that is the case.  The answer I posted below describes how to make the error go away.  If the error is happening and you don't have `main` methods in those classes, I think that would represent a bug.  If that is the case, please file an issue at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues and we can investigate.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown there is a main method in com.base.torque.utils.NaturalOrderComparator but not in the com.base.torque.ExtendedReportsController.

Comment: It looks like Spring Boot is confused and thinks there is a `main` method in `com.base.torque.ExtendedReportsController`.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown - that worked. Thank you.

Comment: I had this in Grails 4. After I did `grails clean` the error was gone.

Comment: @August, yeah, this works for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have multiple classes which contain a `main` method, you can disambiguate with something like this in your `build.gradle`:

```
springBoot {
    mainClassName = 'com.torque.Application'
}
```

Comment: I saw lots of recommendations and suggestions, but only this worked for me.

Comment: This was happening to me pretty much anytime I edited `application.groovy` or `changelog.groovy`.  I assumed it had something to do with those being groovy scripts instead of classes.  I was using the "clean" option and then the next run would work.  This modification worked great.

Comment: `"I assumed it had something to do with those being groovy scripts instead of classes."` - Makes sense.  The issue is related to any classes that have a `main` method in them, and all Groovy scripts have a main method in them (even though you don't see it in the source code).  Glad you got it worked out!

Answer (score 1):

This solved it for me on **Grails 5.2.2**:

```
springBoot {
    mainClass = "com.mypackage.Application"
}
```

Comment: I think the question is targeting Grails 4.0.0.